# Widget is not loaded on AVD

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget

I'm trying to create a widget for Android.
It contains such files:

res/xml/widgetinfo.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:minWidth="146dip"
  android:minHeight="146dip"
  android:updatePeriodMillis="3600000"
  android:initialLayout="@layout/main" />
```

res/layout/main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout >
        <TextView android:text="My widget" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.justmad.thegame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name="WidgetProvider">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widgetinfo" />
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

src/com.test.WidgetProvider:

```
package com.test;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {
}
```

But when I run it in AVD and trying to add my widget it displays the message "Problem loading widget". LogCat shows nothing in verbose mode. So, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to implement `onUpdate()` in your `AppWidgetProvider`.
2. Your layout does not work. You could tell this by trying your layout in, say, an activity. You are missing `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` on the `LinearLayout` and the `TextView`. Also, it is unclear what your `FrameLayout` is doing for you.

Comment: Setting layout helped, thank you! I thought it has default values if not set directly...